# Converting Code from JavaScript to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, json

Please help me.

I have a code in JavaScript.

```
var regiondb = new Object()
regiondb["africa"] = [{value:"1", text:"Cairo"},
                      {value:"2", text:"Casablanka"},
                      {value:"3", text:"Tunis"},
                      {value:"4", text:"Maputu"}];
regiondb["asia"] = [{value:"1", text:"Baku"},
                    {value:"2", text:"Seul"},
                    {value:"3", text:"Tokio"},
                    {value:"4", text:"Ulan-Batar"},
                    {value:"5", text:"Stambul"}];
```

How do convert this code to C# ? 
Am I right in understanding this is `regiondb["asia"] = [{value:"1", text:"Baku"},`  Array?

Comment: @mybirthname I think he's trying to understand the JavaScript code, and trying to map it in his mind to something he already knows.

Comment: @Paul you can be right, I don't have any idea.

Comment: Hello! I want create simple app on C#/ I needed code only on JS. I begginer. Sorry(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var regiondb = new Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String,String>>();
regiondb.Add("africa", new Dictionary<String,String> {
    { "1", "Cairo" },
    { "2", "Casablanka" },
    { "3", "Tunis" },
    { "4", "Maputu" },
});
// Same with asia
```

Then you can access it:

```
// regiondb.Keys           = ["africa", "asia"]
// regiondb["africa"].Keys = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
// regiondb["africa"]["1"] = Cairo
```

That's for a very simple example using standard objects within C#. If you wanted a 1:1 translation, you may want to look into a website like [Json2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/) which will create an object structure (with properties like `value` and `text` to access).

---

Alternative method using actual objects:

```
class RegionDB : IEnumerable<String>, IEnumerable
{
    private IDictionary<String, IEnumerable<City>> continents = new Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<City>>();

    public IEnumerable<String> Continents
    {
        get { return this.continents.Keys; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<City> this[String continent]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.continents.ContainsKey(continent)
                ? this.continents[continent]
                : Enumerable.Empty<City>();
        }
        set
        {
            this.continents[continent] = value ?? Enumerable.Empty<City>();
        }
    }

    public RegionDB()
    {
    }

    #region IEnumerable<String>

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<String>)this).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<String> IEnumerable<String>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.continents.Keys.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}

class City
{
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }

    public City(String text, String value)
    {
        this.Text = text;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
var regiondb = new RegionDB();
regiondb["africa"] = new[]{
    new City("Cairo", "1"),
    new City("Casablanka", "2"),
    new City("Tunis", "3"),
    new City("Maputu", "4")
};
regiondb["asia"] = new[]{
    new City("Baku", "1"),
    new City("Seul", "2"),
    new City("Tokio", "3"),
    new City("Ulan-Batar", "4"),
    new City("Stambul", "5")
};

// List data
foreach (var continent in regiondb) /* or: */ //foreach (var continent in regiondb.Continents)
{
    Console.WriteLine(continent);

    // List cities within
    foreach (var city in regiondb[continent])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tvalue = {0}, text = {1}", city.Value, city.Text);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
africa
  value = 1, text = Cairo
  value = 2, text = Casablanka
  value = 3, text = Tunis
  value = 4, text = Maputu
asia
  value = 1, text = Baku
  value = 2, text = Seul
  value = 3, text = Tokio
  value = 4, text = Ulan-Batar
  value = 5, text = Stambul
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a better answer than mine, since it uses native objects.

Comment: Not better, just different. If i were developing this as a solution, I would most likely create custom objects.

Answer (score 1):

So, it'd be something like this:

```
var regiondb = new Dictionary<String, List<Pair>>(); // where Pair is an object that has a Text and Value property

var africaList = new List<Pair>(){ 
  new Pair { Text = "Cairo", Value = "1" },
  new Pair { Text = "Casablanka", Value = "2"} // and so on
};

regiondb.Add("africa", africaList);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the closest thing in C#:

```
var regiondb = new
{
    africa = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            value = "1",
            text = "Cairo"
        },
        new
        {
            value = "2",
            text = "Casablanka"
        }
        //...
    },

    asia = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            value = "1",
            text = "Baku"
        },
        new
        {
            value = "2",
            text = "Seul"
        }
        //...
    }
};
```

You can access data in it as follows:

regiondb.africa[0].text //Cairo

Comment: Though anonymous objects do have that freedom, that will be difficult to manage across multiple classes/methods.